# mysql command with the -H flag is translating column values to HTML safe strings

Tags: mysql

There seems to be a feature that has been added in mysql's client command line v14.12 which causes the output columns to be converted to web safe output when the -H flag is being used. This is clearly a safety feature but in my case I am using CONCAT to create intentional html links etc. within some of the columns.  Is there a way to turn this apparently new feature off? This problem has arisen in a set of scripts in a shared hosting environment.

Extracting a simpler example:

```
echo select \'\<a\>\'\;
Results desirably in:
select '<a>';

echo select \'\<a\>\'\; | /usr/bin/mysql -s -D database -ppassword
Results desirably in:
<a>

echo select \'\<a\>\'\; | /usr/bin/mysql -H -s -D database -ppassword
Results UNDESIRABLY in:
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TH>&lt;a&gt;</TH></TR><TR><TD>&lt;a&gt;</TD></TR></TABLE>
```

WHAT I WANT, AND USE TO GET IS

```
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TH><a></TH></TR><TR><TD><a></TD></TR></TABLE>
```

which I know isn't valid HTML in this example but in my more complex real examples
it is a full set of matched anchor tags with labels not just a single <a> in the cell.

I want to continue to use the -H flag as I have a large number of scripts yielding
simple internal web readable reports that have links to related reports etc. built
with CONCAT in the SQL results.

It seems to me that the behavior of -H has changed in 14.12 and I can find no
mechanism to switch it off. The --raw/-r flag has no effect on the behavior.

Is the -H flag irrecoverably broken or is there a workaround?
I'm currently using

```
sed -e 's/\&lt;/</g' | sed -e 's/\&gt;/>/g'
```

but there must be a better way within the options of the mysql command itself?

For reference:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -V
/usr/bin/mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.51a, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 5.2


mysql> status;
--------------
/usr/bin/mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.51a, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 5.2

Connection id:          117586
Current database:       database
Current user:           database@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.0.51a-3ubuntu5.8 (Ubuntu)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    latin1
Conn.  characterset:    latin1
UNIX socket:            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 1 day 8 hours 22 min 47 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 4222310  Slow queries: 171  Opens: 122761  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 64  Queries per second avg: 36.222
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're out of luck.

[This bug against MySQL](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27884) is about adding escaping for HTML special characters in output.

According to the bug report, this fix has landed in essentially all the 5.x series.

(As an aside, though I appreciate that you were relying on this behavior, I'd say that I would consider the old, no-escaping behavior to be a bug.)